# How to get image data created by Bootstrap File Input plugin

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, bootstrap-file-upload

I've got the following div that does the work of selecting and showing the selected image, changing the image and cancelling it. All of it is done by the [Bootstrap File Input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input) plugin.

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/512x512/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=NO+IMAGE" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn default btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new">Select image </span>
            <span class="fileinput-exists">Change </span>
        <input type="file" name="..." >
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this Bootstrap File Input plugin create the following `img` element, which holds the data for the image. I need that data so I could send that using AngularJS to my node server and save that image inside a folder on my server.

```
<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAA3=...">
</div>
```

Could somebody help me with getting the dynamically generated `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAIAAAB7GkOtAAAAA3=...` image data by Bootstrap File Input using AngularJS?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution that works? I have the same issue, and needed to get back just created image.

Answer (score 1):

Create form data and append all files to it.

```
var formData = new FormData();

$('#id').on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
    formData.append('file', file);
});
```

Now, `formData` will hold all the files which you have selected and can be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(Your input id).on('fileloaded', function (event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
    console.log(reader.result)
}
```

you can get image data from reader.result, just try